# How to sort entries in raster legend?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, legend, arcgis-desktop

How do I reorder the Value field in a raster? There is no up or down button in it.

[image: Image of ArcGIS legend]

Comment: I bet this is a categorical raster with just seven categories, right?  (Note that the legend is ordered *alphabetically*, not numerically.) :-)

Comment: Yes, correct. So with the numbers it will go from 1, 2, 3, 4 .... so this is how ArcMap read this way. Is there a script that will allow me to do fix the problem ?

Comment: This legend already *is* sorted, given that the slope codes are of alphanumeric type. You could use numeric codes for your categories or you could manually change the order in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option would be to add a new field to the Attribute Table of the raster with a Short/Long Integer type, rank each category based on its correct order, then edit the labels for this new field to reflect the appropriate ranges, like below:

[image: Order with integers, manually define ranges]

A second, slightly more complicated option would be to place each range in a new heading (right-click the value, select Move to Heading, then New Heading...) and name these new headings according to the correct order for the ranges, like this:

[image: Order with headings]

In order to properly symbolize the raster in a legend, however, the option to show the heading in Legend Properties would need to be deactivated.